# Sitecore Rich Text Editor - Using this control in a Webcontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, sitecore

We want to allow a user of the website to edit text without entering the page editor mode, with all the functionality of the normal (sitecore) Rich Text Editor.

Is it possible to use the Sitecore - Rich Text Editor control inside a Webcontrol by just getting this object and adding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rich Text Editor is just a 3rd party tool... so yes, you probably could do this pretty easily.

I believe it's just an older version of [this](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx).  Files you need are probably in `sitecore\shell\controls\Rich Text Editor`.

This is all hearsay though, as I haven't actually done it.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, the Telerik editor is NOT licensed for use in this way. I checked with Sitecore yesterday.

You have to have your own licence or use a different RTE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the licensing of the Telerik RAD editor that comes with Sitecore would allow you to do this. You would need to check with Sitecore.

As an alternative, CKEditor is pretty easy to setup and use. They have open source licensing available. You'd need to add your own code to process the contents and save them into the Sitecore item.

http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

If it's editing text in sitecore items, then you could use the Sitecore Page Editor (or InPage editing). It's an option when you log in, though it might only be from Sitecore 6 and forward, and it requires you to use the Sitecore webcontrols to show content (ie. `<sc:text />` `<sc:image />` etc.).